# When I use angularJS ng-repeat, it doesn't show what I append in javascript

Tags: html, angularjs

> In HTML, I want to display multiple rows of items(tasks timeline). 
>           In each row, gantt-items,gantt-days is used to plot 365 small boxes which are presented 
>           365 days in a year. 
>           And each row need to display a blue block, which means the assigned period of this task. 
>           {{timeline(item.data.sDate,item.data.eDate)}}, each row only contains one blue block.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="item in items.entities">
     <ul class="gantt-items" style="width: 9150px; height: 35px" >
        <li class="gantt-item" >            
           <ul class="gantt-days">
           </ul>       
         </li>          
       </ul>
     {{timeline(item.data.sDate,item.data.eDate)}}
   </li>
 </ul>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);
   function MainCtrl($scope,$resource){
      $(document).ready(function(){
         ...
         for(var i = 1; i < 366; i++){
            $(".gantt-item ul.gantt-days").append('<li class="gantt-day" style="width: 25px"><span style="line-height: 35px; height: 35px">' + year + "-" + d.getMonth() + "-" + d.getDate() + '</span></li>');
            d = new Date(d.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
         }
         ...});

$scope.timeline = function GetLength(startDate, endDate){
    var firstDay = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1);

    var st1 = startDate.split("/");
    var dt1 = new Date(st1[2], st1[1] - 1, st1[0]);

    var st2 = endDate.split("/");
    var dt2 = new Date(st2[2], st2[1] - 1, st2[0]);

    var startPoint = ((dt1.getTime() - firstDay.getTime())/1000/60/60/24)*25;
    var length = (1+(dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime())/1000/60/60/24)*25;
    $(".gantt-item ul.gantt-days").append('<span class="gantt-block" style="left:' + startPoint + 'px; width: ' + length + 'px; height: 27px"><strong class="gantt-block-label">Duration</strong></span>');
};
```

> When I am using ng-repeat, $(".gantt-item ul.gantt-days").append doesn't work.
>     And timeline(item.data.sDate,item.data.eDate) is repeating n times in each row, 
>     which supposes to show only one item per raw of n rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because the elements in the `ng-repeat` directive appear after the DOM compiling.
Try using [`$watch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch):

```
$scope.$watch('items.entities', function(){
    for(var i = 1; i < 366; i++){
        $(".gantt-item ul.gantt-days").append('<li class="gantt-day" style="width: 25px"><span style="line-height: 35px; height: 35px">' + year + "-" + d.getMonth() + "-" + d.getDate() + '</span></li>');
        d = new Date(d.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
     }
});
```

Comment: Thank you of your solution. However, my ng-repeat repeating n times in  every rows, which should display only 1 item per row, and repeating n rows.

Comment: To be more specific of my ng-repeat problem. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177632/multiple-ng-repeat-of-same-item

Comment: @elephant I have the same problem with ng-repeat. I have an array with 5 items and it repeats each item 5 times with total of 25 rows. If I try with 3 items it repeats 3 times for each item. I was not able to reproduce this in JS fiddle or anywhere outside of my project. Can you tell me what was the solution to this issue?