# ng-repeat issue, it is repeating n*n times

Tags: angularjs

> JSON object{"count": 4, "entities": [{"model": "project", "data": {"project": "test1", "startDate": 2013/03/15, "endDate": "2013/03/31"}, "id": 1}, {"model": "project", "data": {"project": "test2", "startDate": 2013/01/15, "endDate": "2013/01/31"}, "id": 2}, {"model": "project", "data": {"project": "test3", "startDate": 2013/02/15, "endDate": "2013/02/31"}, "id": 2}], "model": "project", "method": "get_entities"}

I have a table to show a list of projects with their duration. At left hand side of table I use `ng-repeat` to list down the name of projects, which is `{{item.data.project}}`. It works fine.

At right hand side, each project has corresponding duration (from start date to end date). So I use another `ng-repeat` to get each entity and use `timeline(starDate,endDate)` to draw a block. By right, each row (each project) has one time block, if I have n projects it will show n rows with one time block on each row. However, now it is showing n blocks on each row; on one row it shows all the time blocks of all projects.

```
<div class="content">
   <figure class="gantt">
      <figcaption>All Projects</figcaption>
       <aside>
        <ul class="gantt-labels" style="margin-top: 71px">
         <li class="gantt-label" ng-repeat="item in items.entities"><strong style="line-height:  35px; height: 35px">{{item.data.project}}</strong></li>
        </ul>
       </aside>
    <section class="gantt-data">
    <header>
      <ul class="gantt-months" style="width: 9150px">            
      </ul>
      <ul class="gantt-days" style="width: 9150px">            
      </ul>
    </header>

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items.entities">
        <ul class="gantt-items" style="width: 9150px; height: 35px" >
          <li class="gantt-item" >            
            <ul class="gantt-days">
            </ul>       
          </li>          
        </ul>
      {{timeline(item.data.sDate,item.data.eDate)}}
      </li>
    </ul>

  </section>
</figure>
```

In JavaScript, I use `$(".gantt-item ul.gantt-days").append` to draw 365 pieces of boxes representing 365 days. And timeline method is to draw blue block which is project duration.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);
 function MainCtrl($scope,$resource){
  $(document).ready(function(){
     ...
     $scope.$watch('items.entities', function(){
      for(var i = 1; i < 366; i++){
        $("header ul.gantt-days").append('<li class="gantt-day" style="width: 25px"><strong style="line-height: 35px; height: 35px">' + d.getDate() + '</strong></li>');
        d = new Date(d.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      }
      for(var i = 1; i < 366; i++){
        $(".gantt-item ul.gantt-days").append('<li class="gantt-day" style="width: 25px"><span style="line-height: 35px; height: 35px">' + year + "-" + d.getMonth() + "-" + d.getDate() + '</span></li>');
        d = new Date(d.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      }
    });
     ...});
$scope.timeline = function GetLength(startDate, endDate)
      {
        var firstDay = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1);

        var st1 = startDate.split("/");
        var dt1 = new Date(st1[2], st1[1] - 1, st1[0]);

        var st2 = endDate.split("/");
        var dt2 = new Date(st2[2], st2[1] - 1, st2[0]);

        var startPoint = ((dt1.getTime() - firstDay.getTime())/1000/60/60/24)*25;
        var length = (1+(dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime())/1000/60/60/24)*25;
        $(".gantt-item ul.gantt-days").append('<span class="gantt-block" style="left:' + startPoint + 'px; width: ' + length + 'px; height: 27px"><strong class="gantt-block-label">Duration</strong></span>');
      };
```

Comment: My previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177145/when-i-use-angularjs-ng-repeat-it-doesnt-show-what-i-append-in-javascript)

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Btw, add your items JSON so that we can see what you're iterating over.

Comment: I just added Json and more explanation. Thank you for your help.

Comment: why are you mixing jQuery append with angular? Suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem

Comment: problem is that you create numerous `$(".gantt-item ul.gantt-days")` using ng-repeat, then you append to every one of them 365 times with jQuery

Comment: I have the same problem. I have an array with 5 items. I want ng-repeat to loop through this array and display a directive for each item of the array. Instead what I get is 25 directives in the output (each repeated 5 times). I created a jsFiddle but it seems to be working fine there. So obviosly something else in my code breaks it...